# How to create an animated line plot in R from text file?

Tags: r, animation, imagemagick, line-plot

I want to create an animated plot from a text file with two columns: x = timepoints, y = values.

```
time     values
0       -70.627
1e-5    -68.5964
6e-5    -67.6575
1e-4    -66.6575
1.1e-4  -65.627
0.882119999999  -67.0542
0.882129999999  -67.0847
0.882139999999  -67.0542
0.882149999999  -67.0542
```

I have more than 10000 rows and want 20 frames.

I have tried the following code:

```
data <- read.table("my.txt", header = TRUE)
library(animation)
library(magick)

# Also installed ImageMagick 6.9.9.14 on windows that worked perfectly, checked by convert command

saveGIF({
  for(i in 1:20){
    x <- data$time
    y <- data$values
    plot(x,y)
  }
}, ani.width = 1000, ani.height = 800, movie.name = "data.gif", img.name = "data_Rplot")
```

But, it gives me a static png plot which I can get from:

```
plot(x,y)
```

without any loop.

Please guide.
Thanks.

Comment: You need [to make your example reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610#5963610) by supplying sufficient data to reproduce your plots.

Comment: What kind of animation are you trying to create? The expression inside the `for` loop returns the same plot every time (`x` and `y` stays the same). You probably want the expression to depend on `i`, for instance defining `x <- data$time[1:i]` and `y <- data$values[1:i]`

Comment: You could do something like `library(ggplot2); ggplot(df, aes(time, values, frame = time, cumulative = TRUE)) + geom_point() + geom_line(); gganimate::gganimate()`, but if your actual data has more points than you want rows, you'll need to create a variable to control the frame.

Comment: @ozacha: Thanks, I tried and it worked but showing points and not line. I want to make like this https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Hodgkins_Huxley_Plot.gif

Comment: I want 20 frames means I want to plot full data in 20 frames.

Comment: @alistaire I used it, but getting following error:                              
`Error in if (is.waive(data) || empty(data)) return(cbind(data, PANEL = integer(0))) : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed`

Comment: I am still struggling to get the solution. Any help would be great. Thanks.